# Capitalize text without capitalizing links in python

Tags: python

I need to capitalize a line of input, but if I just use the upper() function, link addresses get capitalized, thus making them unusable.

For example: *"Cool Video www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"*

will turn to: *"COOL VIDEO WWW.YOUTUBE.COM/WATCH?V=DQW4W9WGXCQ"*

The link address has changes and won't work anymore. Is there any way to ignore links?

Comment: There isn't a way to *"ignore links"* as such, because as far as Python is concerned it's just more text. You would have to write something to extract the specific parts of the string you do or don't want to uppercase, deal with them separately, then stick them back together.

Comment: ًWhat part you want to capitalize here?...

Comment: @IronFist Everything except for links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was correct to understand your goal here, then you should first look for the part of string to `upper` case and then joined back with the rest of the original string, this way:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Cool Video -> www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
>>> #Look for the part of string you want to upper case
>>> m = re.search(r'^.*(?=\s+->)', s)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='Cool Video'>
>>> #m.start() and m.end() will give you start and endo position of matched string.
>>> new_s = s[m.start():m.end()].upper() + s[m.end():]
>>> #remember that strings are immutable, so make new one
>>> new_s
'COOL VIDEO -> www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
>>> #OR
>>> new_s = m.group().upper() + s[m.end():]
>>> new_s
'COOL VIDEO -> www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
```

EDIT:

Otherway, is to look for string preceding a link and then apply `upper` method on it:

```
>>> s = "Cool Video www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
>>> m = re.search(r'(.*)(?=www.*)',s)
>>> s = m.group().upper() + s[m.end():]
>>> s
'COOL VIDEO www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
```

Comment: There isn't any markdown. "Cool video -> link" was just an exemple.

Comment: @sageek .. please do edit your questions with a better examples describing *better* your requirements !

Comment: @sageek...check edited answer with alternative solution